# Visual Studio Code retrive UnsupportedClassVersions when run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code:

I have OpenJDK 14 correctly configured. When I try to run my project I receive the follow error:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (class file version 56.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 58.65535

This class is a dependency and it is stored in a Nexus Repository, all this project have been compiled with JDK 12. So I try to uninstall OpenJDK 14 to install OpenJDK 12 but If I do this the project can't build because 'Preview features enabled at an invalid source release level 12, preview can be enabled only at source level 14'.

But the same project is correctly build in Eclipse for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the "Java: clean the Java language server workspace" command?

Or

Updating java extension to the latest version.

As you described, the first time you try to take JRE 14 to run the file which was compiled
with javac 12, then you downgrade to JDK 12 and want to use JRE 12 to run the file. But you get the error of 'Preview features enabled at an invalid source ...'. It seems like a cache causes this. Or did you use some preview features of JDK 14 in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with following steps:

1 - Install JDK 12 and configure it.
2 - The project was imported from Eclipse so there are all related files in settings. One of this is "org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs" go into it and modifie the value of "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures" to disabled.

Seems like VSCode reads all the settings and replicate the 
behavior of Eclipse IDE.